# Upgrading Docker in Amazon linux AMI to 1.11.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

The docker version in my amazon linux is 1.9.1 and I want to upgrade it to 1.11.1.
But yum update doesn't upgrade the docker version and it still at 1.9.1.

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-10-215-0-163 4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Mar 16 17:15:34 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ docker info
Containers: 4
Images: 9
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: devicemapper
 Pool Name: docker-202:1-263639-pool
 Pool Blocksize: 65.54 kB
 Base Device Size: 10.74 GB
 Backing Filesystem:
 Data file: /dev/loop0
 Metadata file: /dev/loop1
 Data Space Used: 6.489 GB
 Data Space Total: 107.4 GB
 Data Space Available: 12.69 GB
 Metadata Space Used: 4.444 MB
 Metadata Space Total: 2.147 GB
 Metadata Space Available: 2.143 GB
 Udev Sync Supported: true
 Deferred Removal Enabled: false
 Deferred Deletion Enabled: false
 Deferred Deleted Device Count: 0
 Data loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/data
 Metadata loop file: /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/devicemapper/metadata
 Library Version: 1.02.93-RHEL7 (2015-01-28)
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 4.4.5-15.26.amzn1.x86_64
Operating System: Amazon Linux AMI 2016.03
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 3.679 GiB
Name: ip-10-215-0-163
ID: EJNW:5DZK:I7XD:T7LC:WBC2:POG4:3YVS:HK2F:MQFY:INCM:ZEUQ:UC6X
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just using yum update, it won't work, because it will only look at the amazon yum repositories that they have setup. You will need to install a yum repo that has a newer version of Docker. I recommend going to the official Docker yum repository to get your Docker packages.

These directions are for CentOS, but they should work for Amazon linux, since they are both RedHat derivatives.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/centos/

Comment: `yum install docker-engine
https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/latest/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
Trying other mirror.`

Comment: Did you follow the directions on the page I linked too? I don't see that command anywhere on that page. You can also try this `curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` it will set everything up for you and install it.

Comment: I tried using the script also but still it installs 1.9.1 only. Adding centos repo in Amazon Linux doesn't allow me to install docker-engine and I think  amzn-main.repo  only maintaining docker version for Amazon Linux which have the version 1.9.1

Comment: the instructions in this link use the url
`https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/centos/$releasever/`
however, `$releasever` is not defined on my AMI instances. So hard 7 (or 6 for centos 6) instead